# Time-based trigger doesn't run on copy of a template document with bound script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, triggers

I have a template document with a bound script that does some basic field validation. In addition to a menu item, I create a time-based trigger in `onOpen(e)` to run the validation function every minute. All of this works perfectly when I open the template document (I've granted the permission to access the document when prompted).

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger(TRIGGER_FUNCTION_NAME)
  .timeBased()
  .everyMinutes(1)
  .create();
```

When I create a copy of this template document, the time-based trigger doesn't run for other users. From [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#restrictions) and [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization#permissions_and_types_of_scripts) I read that the installed trigger would run with my credentials which is ok. But I do not understand why the trigger won't run in the copied document for another user with EDIT rights (or prompt for rights)?

Is this approach feasible? Add-ons can only run once per hour so I cannot use that and there is no `onEdit()` trigger for documents. Does the `onOpen()` have to also be an installed trigger for this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Your time-driven trigger is an installable trigger, but I assume that your `onOpen(e)` trigger isn't

So yes, if your `onOpen(e)` function is meant to install a time-driven trigger - this is a request that requires authorization and consequently cannot be carried out from within a simple `onOpen(e)` trigger as specified [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions).

Thus, unfortunately you would need to add manually an installable `onOpen` trigger to each copy of the template.

Comment: Thank you @ziganotschka for your quick answer, would you happen to know if I can use the [DocumentTriggerBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/document-trigger-builder#onopen) in the simple `onOpen()` trigger or using an external API to create the installable onOpen trigger?

Comment: Unfortunately the question to both is no: Any usage of trigger builder requires authentication, this is why it does not work for other users the way you have set it up now. When it comes to external APIs - there is the [Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api), but it explicitly says [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/execute): `The API cannot create Apps Script triggers`.

Comment: The way to go would be creating a [custom menu](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus) that would be added on simple `onOpen(e)` and allow the user to give his permission to run a function that would run the trigger builder.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining this @ziganotschka! It seems like I need to go back to the drawing board with my plan.